# UiDevice.openNotification() does not work with windowFullscreen=true

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-uiautomator

One of my [UiAutomator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator.html) tests fails on one of my testing devices because

```
_uiDevice.openNotification()
```

fails to open the notification area.
Contrary to the [documentation of this function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#openNotification()), I retrieve `true` as result.

If I set `<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>` (previously, this was `true`), the notifications are opened correctly.

But this issue only happens on one of my devices (Sony Xperia Z3) while another one (Samsung Galaxy S5) succeeds in opening the notification, no matter if the activity is fullscreen or not.

My (initial) style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/ioxp_yellow</item>
</style>
```

In my manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

The excerpt from my test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityAutomatorTest {

    @Test
    public void testNotifications() throws UiObjectNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException,
            NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        //...
        Assert.assertTrue("Could not open device notifications", _uiDevice.openNotification());
        String notificationString = context.getString(R.string.downloadService_title_workspace, serverWsId);
        UiObject2 notification = _uiDevice.wait(Until.findObject(By.text(notificationString)),
                UI_TIMEOUT);
        Assert.assertNotNull(notification); // THIS FAILS
    }

    @Before
    public void startMainActivityFromHomeScreen() {
        // Initialize UiDevice instance

        _uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

        // Start from the home screen
        _uiDevice.pressHome();

        // Wait for launcher
        final String launcherPackage = _uiDevice.getLauncherPackageName();
        Assert.assertNotNull(launcherPackage);
        _uiDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(launcherPackage).depth(0)), UI_TIMEOUT);

        // Launch the app
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
        final Intent intent = context.getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
        Assert.assertNotNull(intent);
        // Clear out any previous instances
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);

        // Wait for the app to appear
        _uiDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID).depth(0)), UI_TIMEOUT);
    }
}
```

Is this a bug in the automator framework or am I doing something wrong?